# How to get entity manager object in php template?

Tags: symfony

I'm using php templates instead of Twig templates in symfony2.3.

Inside this I need to write a doctrine code in PHP template.
So I'm trying to create object for entity manager using following code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT t FROM MyBundle:$TableName t $Condition ");

$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

But its not working.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Views shouldn't need to execute queries. Just execute this code in your controller and send it to your view.

Comment: Touki is right! Read a bit about the MVC (Model-View-Controller) design pattern. All interaction with the database and processing the results should happen from within a controller method. The code you want to write is definitively a violation of the MVC-constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You must not do this inside template. Instead, design your logic in controller and render controller in the template:

```
<?php echo $view['actions']->render(
new ControllerReference(
    'MyBundle:MyController:myMethod'
))
?>
```

In the method, write your code.

Comment: I tried this one.`code`?php echo $view['actions']->render(
new ControllerReference(
    'MyBundle:MyController:myMethod'
))but its not working ..please sent me any sample code
?>